# Bulk delete orders

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a bunch of test orders and I'd like to remove them. Is there a way to bulk remove all of the orders without uninstalling/installing the Ubercart module?

Obviously, I'd first backup the database with a simple `drush sql-dump`.

Comment: You can try flushing the orders MySQL table using phpMyAdmin or any db management tool. If you do please backup your database and test if everything is ok.

Comment: Have you done this before ? Are you sure you don't forget some child tables like `uc_order_line_items` ? It won't bother Drupal to have these lines left in your tables but it's not a good advice to give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would discourage you from messing with the database unless you really know what you're doing. You should better use the API and the function [`uc_order_delete()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--ubercart--uc_order--uc_order.module/function/uc_order_delete/6).

Have a look at this example script:

```
<?php
  include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

  global $user;

  if ($user->uid == 1) {
    $result = db_query("select order_id from uc_orders");
    while($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
      //# uncomment below to view an order and exit
      //# usefull to write a query to only delete certain orders
      //print_r($row);
      //exit;
      print "deleting order $row->order_id\n";
      uc_order_delete($row->order_id); // comment this out for testing
    }
  } else {
    print "Only Administrater could deleter orders.";
  }
?>
```

Source: [Delete all orders in Ubercart](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/05/22/drupal-delete-all-orders-in-ubercart/).

Comment: Or use this [Bulk delete orders](http://drupal.org/project/vbo_delete_uc_orders) module , so you can do bulk delete from _admin > store > order_ itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a view created with the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to delete orders.

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.